# Debug/Print from Multiple Functions with Dependencies

Tags: python, function, object, printing, attributes

I am trying to debug a program in a Jupyter Notebook to validate the process and its outputs.

What I am essentially after is:

1. access the `attr` object attributes along with other functions output - before and after manipulations are performed within the same function
2. access outputs from dependent functions (i.e. functions that require inputs from other functions)

Here's a snippet of my code, it is incomplete on purpose - please treat it as a pseudo code.
My question is about how to **access the various function outputs and print them**, similarly to a debugging process.

Marking / how to read:

1. There's an arrow (<--) next to what I am interested in printing to the console.
2. (---) signifies different cells in the notebook.
3. (...) signifies irrelevant code or manipulations to data that have been omitted

**Please see my questions below**

NOTE: df_rdd is a PySpark dataframe.

```
...
---
df_rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict(True))

---
class ClassAttr:
    def __init__(self, list_of_input_arguments): 
        ...     
        self.temp_matrix = {}
        
    def attribute(self, data, log=True):
        self.states = ...
        if log:
            print(self.states) ## <--

        self.matrix = ...              

        if log:
            print(self.matrix) ## <-- (1st instance before manipulation) 

        self.matrix = ...

        if log:
            print(self.matrix) ## <-- (2nd instance after manipulation)
        

    def attribute_deletion(self, item_to_delete, data):      
           ...
            return self.temp_matrix[item_to_delete] ## <--
    
    def probability_to_convert(self, data): 
        prob = ...
        return prob  ## <--     
    
    def deletion_perc(self, item_to_delete, data):           
        self.deletion_perc(item_to_delete, data)        
        prob = self.probability_to_convert(data)                                        
                           
        prob_delete = self.temp_matrix[item_to_delete][self.temp_matrix[item_to_delete].index.get_loc(self.start_time)]

        deletion_perc = round(1 - prob_delete/prob,2)
        return deletion_perc ## <--
    
    def print_result(self, data):
        self.attribute(data, log=False)

        for col in self.matrix.columns:
            if col not in (self.conversion, self.start):        
                deletion_perc = self.deletion_perc(col, data)

                deletion_perc_list.append(deletion_perc)
                
        deletion_perc_result = pd.DataFrame({'first_event': first_event_date,
                                            'last_event': last_event_date,
                                            'deletion_perc': deletion_perc_list
                                            })
    
        return deletion_perc_result ## <--
---
attr = ClassAttr(
        list_of_class_attributes...
       )

def the_function(x):
    data_points = pd.DataFrame(x)
    return attr.print_result(data_points).to_dict('records')
---
results = df_rdd.groupBy(lambda x: (x['start_time'],x['num'])).mapValues(the_function)
final_results = results.flatMap(lambda x: x[1]).map(lambda x: Row(**x)).toDF()
```

Basically, my main questions are -

1. how do I enable the printout from the following (currently this
   isn't being printed):

```
def function(something=True)    
    if something:
       print() ## <--
```

2. how do I print the "deeper" function outputs (from functions that require inputs from other functions)?

What I've tried so far..

1. invoke the first function and separate the rest of them into different cells so I can see the printouts separately - then realized they probably must to be in the same block under the class definition.
2. define  a new function and invoke it to retrieve the attributes.

In hindsight it doesn't make much sense but had to give it a try...
I am sure there is a simpler way to do this, but I am a little rusty and searching Google didn't yield very helpful answers.

Would appreciate if someone can explain how to approach the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use debugger mode available in all the IDE's, if not check youtube for how to use debugger mode
This will help you to understand the flow of your code line by line as well as value of the varibles.
And you can do some Evaluation in debugging mode(PyCharm is good for python)

Comment: Thank you - it looks like the debugger option in my IDE is greyed out, and it seems that I don't have access to a kernel that supports debugging. Moving the code to other platforms isn't feasible due to database connection issues. My first thought was to use pycharm, however, this isn't possible in this case. Any other ideas?